# Unhandled exception: FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1) 12 2 5.30

Tags: dart, unhandled-exception, formatexception

I am trying to solve a problem in URI online judge problem number 1010. Running the code in my IDE throws no error. However, it throws runtime error in URI.

```
12 2 5.30
^

#0      int._throwFormatException (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:131)
#1      int._parseRadix (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:142)
#2      int._parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:100)
#3      int.parse (dart:core-patch/integers_patch.dart:63)
#4      main (file:///judge/judge-7457cda102c440638d0db570b8eed561.d/Main.dart:7)
#5      _startIsolate. (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:301)
#6      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:168)
```

Here is my Code

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  int a, b;
  double c, result;

  a = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  b = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  c = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  result = b * c;

  a = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  b = int.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  c = double.parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);
  result += b * c;
  String pagar = result.toStringAsFixed(2);

  print('VALOR A PAGAR: R\$ $pagar');
}
```

Thnak you all in advance.

Comment: So your input is a single line as `12 2 5.30`? If that is the case, you need to split the numbers before parsing.